# Apache redirect adding name twice in url

Tags: linux, apache, tomcat

I have an apache web server that is redirecting from another server. When I first navigate to the URL it adds the directory name twice.

Example path: //10.0.00.555:8080/**name**/app

on initial load I get

Path changes to: //10.0.00.555:8080/**namename**/app

Obviously, this path is not found and the site does not display it.

This is not an issue after removing the second name and the browser cashes the site but needs to be fixed for the initial loading of the page.

Comment: Please show your htaccess file. Clear the browser caches and try loading it, or try loading it with `curl http://10.0.00.555:8080/name/app -Ik` and show the output.